# Database design: Transaction Status , in journal or in transaction table?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, data-modeling, accounting

Should the transaction status be in the transaction journal table or in the transaction table?

Your journal links one or more transactions,
Example payment to bob

Your account DR $10
Bob account CR $10

Where should the status be stored?

Answer (score 0):

What status? There are only 2: valid, cancelled (which should basically be the flag for the counter-transaction, nothing else - linking the canceled one to what cancel it).

There are no other states - the transfer is recorded so done. Or what do you talk of?